# RedHat Enterprise Linux 6 - Edit Hostname

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, hostname

I'm currently trying to edit my hostname in a RedHat Enterprise Linux 6 virtual machine but I have some problem.

I tried using the function `hostname` like this:

```
hostname -v bravo.cmweb.com
```

And it works, I call the function and the hostname as been edited successfuly.

Then, I reboot the machine et then, oups, the hostname is again `localhost.localdomain`.

Now, I want to ask: how I can edit permanently the hostname in Linux??

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to do a little bit more than using `hostname`.  The following link below should solve your problem. [Change your Hostname without Rebooting in RedHat Linux](http://www.xenocafe.com/tutorials/linux/redhat/change_hostname_without_reboot/index.php)

> Make sure you are logged in as root and move to /etc/sysconfig and
>   open the network file in vi.
>
> ```
> cd /etc/sysconfig
> vi network
> ```
>
> Look for the HOSTNAME line and replace it with the new hostname you
>   want to use. In this example I want to replace localhost with redhat9.
>
> ```
> HOSTNAME=redhat9
> ```
>
> When you are done, save your changes and exit vi. Next we will edit
>   the /etc/hosts file and set the new hostname.
>
> ```
> vi /etc/hosts
> ```
>
> In hosts, edit the line that has the old hostname and replace it with
>   your new one.
>
> ```
> 192.168.1.110     redhat9
> ```
>
> Save your changes and exit vi. The changes to /etc/hosts and
>   /etc/sysconfig/network are necessary to make your changes persistent
>   (in the event of an unscheduled reboot).
>
> Now we use the hostname program to change the hostname that is
>   currently set.
>
> ```
> hostname redhat9
> ```
>
> And run it again without any parameters to see if the hostname
>   changed.
>
> ```
> hostname
> ```
>
> Finally we will restart the network to apply the changes we made to
>   /etc/hosts and /etc/sysconfig/network.
>
> ```
> service network restart
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The hostname in a Red Hat system is configured in the file `/etc/sysconfig/network`.

Edit the file and add or edit a line such as this:

```
HOSTNAME="bravo.cmweb.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this [how to](http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-change-the-hostname-on-rhel-6-server/) to change the hostname on RHEL 6 Server. Reboot is required for both options.

*You can follow either the first option **OR** the second one.*

1. Modify `/etc/sysconfig/network`

   ```
   vi /etc/sysconfig/network

   NETWORKING=yes
   HOSTNAME=MyNewHostname.localdomain
   ```

   - Save and reboot your server.
2. Type the following command to enter GUI mode.

   ```
   [root@localhost ~]# system-config-network
   ```

   - Go to “DNS Configuration”.
   - Modify your preferred hostname and click OK.
   - Click ” Save & Quit”.
   - Save and reboot your server.